# Heroku CLI Segmentation Fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Whenever I run a heroku command (heroku restart, heroku apps, etc., even just heroku) I get the following message:

```
/Users/jjjj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/multi_json-1.9.0/lib/multi_json/adapters/oj.rb:20: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling multi_json.  I am hesitant to rm -rf the heroku directories and reinstall.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @JasonMalcolm Does my answer below work for you?

Comment: @JasonMalcolm I have forgotten what I did about this problem, though I got around it somehow.  I use rvm and may have just switched rubies but don't remember.

Comment: I finally got it figured out for. Heroku pushed a version of the Toolbelt that broke some people's config. There is a better description of the break/fix here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/932.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get around this by running `bundle exec heroku restart`, but YMMV.