# Heroku Segmentation fault when I run heroku -version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have just installed heroku and then I want to verify my installation, so I run

```
heroku --version
```

but I got a lot of error message

```
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

I have searched for the answers on stack overflow, [one said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418894/heroku-cli-segmentation-fault) , I have tried

```
bundle exec heroku restart
```

but it did not work for me, since I still got the error.

I also tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540155/rails-segmentation-fault-on-mac-osx-with-rvm/10540282) , that is, I run

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

but it did worked either.

My system is Mac OSX Sierra. Could anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow instruction uninstalling Heroku Toolbelt: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#uninstalling-the-heroku-cli

Make sure you have brew installed: 
http://brew.sh/

Then install Heroku Toolbelt this way:
`brew install heroku`

Comment: Yes, brew install fix this problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Heroku docs (here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install) this should be updated to:

```
brew install heroku/brew/heroku
```